# Using the Rails console to delete odd-numbered records

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, command-line, console

I'd like to delete records with odd numbered ID's from `Hero` table using the Rails console. Would someone be so kind as to suggest a way for me to do this? 
Kind Regards,

Ryan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
Hero.where('id MOD(2)!=0').destroy_all
```